# How can I upgrade all scoped packages to particular tag version?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I want to upgrade all scoped packages to specific tag.

ex.

Suppose I've multiple packages installed from some scope. `@scope/pkg1`, `@scope/pkg2`, etc. All the packages have multiple tags other than `latest`, like `stable`. Is there a way I upgrade `pkg1` and `pkg2` in scope `@scope` to `stable`.

Following works only for `--latest`

```
yarn upgrade -S @scope --latest
```

But above command does not work for other tags, like `stable`. We can surely do it one by one, like

```
yarn upgrade -S @scope/pkg1@stable
```

Is there a way, I can upgrade all the packages in particular scope to specific tag version.

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose the following shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat ./package.json \
  | jq -r '.dependencies | keys | .[]' \
  | grep '@scope/' \
  | while read -r dep; do yarn upgrade -S "${dep}@stable"; done
```

Comment: Thanks @alexander-alexandrov, I wrote some Node.js code to get it working.